# rsync copy file without user and password less access

Tags: linux, shell, security, rsync

Explain below mention command we are not passing username as well password still we can do rsync.

```
 rsync -avz rsync.apache.org::apache-dist /path/to/mirror
```

Answer (score 1):

`rsync.apache.org::apache-dist` provides a public `rsync` server.  There is no need to authenticate with username or password to download things from it.

If possible, choose an Apache mirror that is close to you.  A list of official (full) mirror servers are available at https://www.apache.org/mirrors/dist.html  (see the "type" column for which ones supports `rsync`).

Comment: Thanks, Yes i got this command from mention URL you shared. but I wan to know how rsync command work without auth.
And what is public rsync server ?

Comment: @ankuj It works because the `rsync` server is not expecting any authentication.  It is a _public_ server, available to anyone.  "Public" in this regard means "the general public", i.e. anyone that knows how to access it.